# how/resources to compile a procedural language into [sql]

Tags: sql, compiler-construction, programming-languages, parsing

I am looking into the possibility/feasibility/resources for building a cross compiler which takes a procedural or Object Oriented language like C, or Java and compiling it into SQL. I understand that the advantage of SQL code is performing set operations which is fundamentally different from procedural languages which generally process 1 at a time. If anyone has done this before, or if it is thought of as too complicated to do or any other ideas/concerns/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Philip

Comment: Isn't that sort of what a DAL like SQLAlchemy does? Obviously it's a little different, as it does it on the fly. Cool idea, though.

Comment: Standard SQL doesn't generally have the constructs that procedural or OO languages have. Examples: local variables, function/method calls, loops (!), if/then.

Unless you're talking about a specific dialect, like PL/SQL (Oracle), which has all that, and more.

Comment: Wow SQLAlchemy is very cool but not what I am looking for per se. An example might be a for loop which changes each item with an if statement into an update where sql statement like this...

For(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
if(i%2==0)
   x=7;
}

into SQL

update tbl
set x=7 
where i % 2=0

note: at this point I am looking for any tools resources for any flavor of SQL which can be generated from the procedural/OO languages. Thanks for the comments :)